# App crashes when typing text into TextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making a text box send a word to the next page. However, it turns off as soon as I put a letter in the text box.

I checked the RAM and cpu status with the profiler because I said there might be a performance issue when I googled, but there was no significant change.

After that, I found that there could be a RAM leak due to the foreach, but the foreach at the bottom is before we move on to the next page, so I don't think it's going to be a problem.

Finally, I've tried debugging, but I'm a beginner, so I don't know exactly where to write the breakpoints. I failed because the app turned off in the text entry stage.

I'm use android compose. and here is my code.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            BadmintonTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    MyApp(viewModel = MainViewModel())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun SinglesLayout(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("Red")
        TextField(
            value = viewModel.playerNames.getOrNull(0) ?: "",
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.playerNames[0] = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        )
        Text("Blue")
        TextField(
            value = viewModel.playerNames.getOrNull(1) ?: "",
            onValueChange = {
                viewModel.playerNames[1] = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        )
    }
}
@Composable
fun MyApp(viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    var isSingles by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "main") {
        composable("main") {
            MainScreen(navController, viewModel)
        }
        composable("next") {
            NextScreen(navController, viewModel)
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { isSingles = !isSingles }) {
            Text(
                text = if (isSingles) {
                    "doubles"
                } else {
                    "singles"
                }
            )
        }
        if (isSingles) {
            SinglesLayout(viewModel = viewModel)
        } else {
            DoublesLayout(viewModel = viewModel)
        }
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("next") }) {
            Text("connect")
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun NextScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        viewModel.playerNames.forEach() { name ->
            Text(name)
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController, viewModel: MainViewModel) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Button(onClick = { navController.navigate("next") }) {
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find bug on debug mode.

Comment: What does "it turns off" mean? If possible, please share a video demonstrating the undesirable behavior.

Comment: @Luke Park Welcome to StackOverflow! If an answer resolved your issue, you can mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out why your App is crashing and how to analyze logs, check out this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this).

My guess is that you have not properly initialized the `playerNames` Array in your ViewModel.

Also be aware that you need to declare each element of the Array using `mutableStateOf` so that Jetpack Compose can observe changes made to an element.

You can try to change your code like this:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Text("Red")
    TextField(
        value = viewModel.playerNames[0].value,
        onValueChange = {
            viewModel.playerNames[0].value = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    )
    Text("Blue")
    TextField(
        value = viewModel.playerNames[1].value,
        onValueChange = {
            viewModel.playerNames[1].value = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
    )
}
```

And define the Array in your ViewModel as follows:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // initialize Array with two elements and mutableStateOf
    val playerNames = List(2) { mutableStateOf("") }
}
```